# How can I deploy QuestDB on GCP?

Tags: questdb

I would like to deploy the time series database QuestDB on GCP, but I do not see any instructions on the documentation. Could I get some steps?

Comment: Do you mean Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Hi, yes this is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a few shorts steps on Compute Engine. When creating a new instance, choose the region and instance type, then:

- In the "Container" section, enable "Deploy a container image to this VM instance"
- type `questdb/questdb:latest` for the "Container image"

This will pull the latest QuestDB docker image and run it on your instance when launching. The rest of the setup steps are setting firewall rules to allow networking on the ports you require:

- port 9000 - web console & REST API
- port 8812 - PostgreSQL wire protocol

Source of this info is an [ETL tutorial by Gabor Boros](https://dev.to/gaborboros/automating-etl-jobs-on-time-series-data-with-questdb-on-google-cloud-platform-1j8k) which deploys QuestDB to GCP and uses Cloud Functions for loading and processing data from a storage bucket.